# C # Selenium problem to click a button with webdriver when there are 2 identical buttons on the page

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, findelement

I ask for a hand to be able to click a button with webdriver.findelement;  the problem is that in the html the two buttons are identical in all properties and I cannot understand how to choose between the 2. The only field that changes is aria-labeledby but it changes at each refresh and therefore it is impossible to capture it with findElement .  I leave the images of the code of the two buttons below.  The tags are contained in a span, which has the usual characteristics for both buttons.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX0Oa.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doHxw.jpg)

Comment: can you share a link to that page or give us entire HTML code of that page as a text, not as a picture?

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as plain text formatted in code blocks. Be sure to include a [repro].

Answer (score 0):

With the limited amount of information it is hard to say for sure, but in this event I would normally try xpath or full xpath. You didnt specify what you gave find element to use but Xpath should work.